# Is it a good idea to implement synchronous methods with BeginXXX and EndXXX?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, synchronous

I'm implementing a network library, and I'm making it asynchronous (with beginxxx-endxxx, not async/await). I also want to leave some synchronous methods, which I plan on implementing like

```
xxx()
{
    var r=BeginXXX();
    EndXXX(r);
}
```

I know that doing something similar with async/await is a bad idea and will cause deadlocks.

Is this a good idea with Begin/End, or will this cause any problems down the stream/kill app's performance?

Comment: I think you are confusing deadlocks with infinite loops, as far as I know you could define timeouts with async and await. So you would only have need to implement 'Begin' and 'End' methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way of doing synchronous operations will be less performant, in particular around memory allocations. Immediately blocking on the `IAsyncResult` also (usually) requires you to allocate your `AsyncWaitHandle`, so you're also allocating an extra kernel object for each request.

In the end, it just depends on how performant you *need* your synchronous apps to be. If this is a general-purpose, widely-used library (e.g., `System.Net.Sockets.Socket`), then you should definitely not take this approach. If it's just a basic library and you don't need to support extreme scenarios, then you could probably get away with wrappers like this.